# Service autorestart not working in pyjnius (kivy) service

Tags: python, android, service, kivy, buildozer

I am trying to write an app with a background service, I'm compiling it with buildozer and it works, kind of. The problem is that the service doesn't auto restart after clearing recent apps on android! What might be the issue? I wrote an example for you that I'm trying to work on:

**main.py**

```
class ServiceApp(App):
    def startservice(self, *args):
        if platform == "android":
            from jnius import autoclass
            service = autoclass('org.codeclickers.testservice.ServiceMyservice')
            mActivity = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity').mActivity
            argument = ''
            service.start(mActivity, argument)
            print("service Started!")

    def build(self):

        return Button(text="start service", on_press=self.startservice())
```

**service.py**

```
from jnius import autoclass
import time
from plyer import notification

if __name__ == "__main__":
    PythonService = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonService')
    PythonService.mService.setAutoRestartService(True)
    print("service Started")

    while True:
        notification.notify(title='service', message=str("Testing"))
        time.sleep(3)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your service is not being restarted because of the `if __name__ == "__main__"` condition on service.py.  After all, this condition is fulfilled when the script you are running is the main one.

I myself do not know about these services. But as I understand it, the main program is main.py, and the called program is service.py, and your `if __name__ == "__main__"` condition with the following code will only work if it is executed in the main program. So, I think you just need to remove the condition, and then your service will restart.

Comment: @Yaros The entire code is fine but, according to the Kivy Official Documentation, Kivy background services can only be started from the `on_start` function. So, do this.